# OpenGL: How to render perfect rectangular gradient?

Tags: c++, opengl, gradient, glsl

I can render triangular gradient with simply just one triangle and using glColor for each corner.

But how to render perfect rectangular gradient? I tried with one quad, but the middle will get ugly seam. I also tried with texture of 2x2 size, it was like it should be done: proper blending from each corner, but the texture sampling precision becomes unprecise when stretched too much (i started to see pixels bigger than 1x1 size).

Is there some way of calculating this in a shader perhaps?

--

**Edit:** Link to images were broken(removed).

Comment: What version of OpenGL are you using?  Forward or compatible context?

Comment: i would like this to be compatible with as low version as possible.

Comment: That looks like two triangles rather than a single quad (the center is interpolated between two corners, not all four.

Comment: @ben, yes... quad is formed from two triangles, how can i make it without triangles in opengl...? by the way, i used GL_QUADS there.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, look at my new image now, it just doesnt work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, the kind of gradient you want relies on 4 colors at each pixel, where OpenGL typically only interpolates input over triangles (so 3 inputs). Getting the perfect gradient is not possible just with the standard interpolants.

Now, as you mentioned, a 2x2 texture can do it. If you did see precision issues, I suggest switching the format of the texture to something that typically requires more precision (like a float texture).

Last, and as you mentioned also in your question, you can solve this with a shader. Say you pass an extra attribute per-vertex that corresponds to (u,v) = (0,0) (0,1) (1,0) (1,0) all the way to the pixel shader (with the vertex shader just doing a pass-through).

You can do the following in the pixel shader (note, the idea here is sound, but I did not test the code):

Vertex shader snippet:

```
varying vec2 uv;
attribute vec2 uvIn;

uv = uvIn;
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform vec3 color0;
uniform vec3 color1;
varying vec2 uv;

// from wikipedia on bilinear interpolation on unit square:
// f(x,y) = f(0,0)(1-x)(1-y) + f(1,0)x(1-y) + f(0,1)(1-x)y + f(1,1) xy. 
// applied here:
// gl_FragColor = color0 * ((1-x)*(1-y) + x*y) + color1*(x*(1-y) + (1-x)*y)
// gl_FragColor = color0 * (1 - x - y + 2 * x * y) + color1 * (x + y - 2 * x * y)
// after simplification:
// float temp = (x + y - 2 * x * y);
// gl_FragColor = color0 * (1-temp) + color1 * temp;
gl_FragColor = mix(color0, color1, uv.u + uv.v - 2 * uv.u * uv.v);
```

Comment: shouldnt it be `gl_FragColor = mix(...)` ? also arent those float3 and float2 supposed to be `vec3` and `vec2` ? could you show how i pass the extra attributes, and what changes i need in vertex shader too? i dont quite follow this...

Comment: @Rookie: Indeed. I play with too many languages... Fixed the ones you mentioned, and added a bit on the vertex shader. What exactly don't you follow ? The idea is to implement the bilinear filtering you're after in the shader, using the uv's we passed in to figure out where in the square the pixels of interest are.

Comment: if i understand correctly, i must use glTexCoord2f() with glColor3f() and glVertex2f() ? but which part of the code knows that uvIn means the texture coords... that part i dont get

Comment: also i dont get it how i fill the color0 and color1 with corresponding values from vertex shader (or where else?)

Comment: @Rookie: ah, well, I did not realize you had no experience with shaders... you can use glTexCoord for the uvs if you want (the generic attributes I'm using use a different API, glGetVertexAttribLocation+glVertexAttrib). In that case, simply replace the uvIn with the predefined gl_MultiTexCoord0.uv. Similarly, for the uniform, you need to use glGetUniformLocation+glUniform3f). You'd better check a glsl tutorial to understand the concepts.

Comment: oh,  isee, but how about the color0 and color1...? which logic those are picked ?

Comment: @Rookie: As I said, use glGetUniformLocation+glUniform3f for the uniform variables (that's the color0 and color1). Or you can use constants directly in the shader.

Comment: yes, but if i send 2 colors per vertex, which colors i send from the 4 corner colors...? that part i dont get.

Comment: @Rookie: Uniforms get sent per full draw (i.e. before glBegin, in your case). Hence the "uniform" name. I only have 2 colors because it seemed you wanted the same color at the top right and bottom left, same for the other 2. Look at the math in the code comments to see how from the formal f(x,y) that has 4 constants, I moved to only 2 that share color0 and color1

Comment: oh i see.. well you should have told that your code doesnt calculate perfect gradient in your answer, (in case someone else wonders why it doesnt work). i'll just make my own calculations then... (cant understand that formula really XD)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is because you use a quad. The quad is drawn using two triangles, but the triangles are not in the orientation that you need.

If I define the quad vertices as:

- *A*: bottom left vertex
- *B*: bottom right vertex
- *C*: top right vertex
- *D*: top left vertex

I would say that the quad is composed by the following triangles:

- *A B D*
- *D B C*

The colors assigned to each vertex are:

- *A*: yellow
- *B*: red
- *C*: yellow
- *D*: red

Keeping in mind the geometry (the two triangles), the pixels between *D* and *B* are result of the interpolation between red and red: indeed, red!

The solution would be the a geometry with two triangles, but orientated in a different way:

- *A B C*
- *A C D*

But probably you will no get the exact gradient, since in middle of quad you will get a full yellow, instead of a yellow mixed with red. So, I suppose you can achieve the exact result using 4 triangles (or a triangle fan), in which the centered  vertex is the interpolation between the yellow and the red.

---

Wooop! Effetively the result is not what I was expecting. I thought the gradient was produced by linear interpolation between colors, but surely is not (I really need to setup the LCD color space!). Indeed, the most scalable solution is rendering using fragment shaders.

Keep the solution proposed by *Bahbar*. I would advice to start the implementation of a pass-through vertex/fragment shader (specifying only vertices and colors you should get the previous result); then, start playing with the *mix* function and the texture coordinate passed to the vertex shader.

**You really need to understand the rendering pipeline with programmable shaders**: vertex shader is called once per vertex, fragment shader is called once per fragment (without multisampling, a fragment is a pixel; with multisampling, a a pixel is composed by a many fragments which are interpolated to get the pixel color).

The vertex shader take the input parameters (uniforms and inputs; uniforms are constant for all vertices issued between glBegin/glEnd; inputs are characteristic of each vertex shader instance (4 vertices, 4 vertex shader instances).

A fragment shader takes as input the vertex shader outputs which has produced the fragment (due the rasterization of triangles, lines and points). In the *Bahbar* answer the only output is the *uv* variable (common to both shader sources).

In you case, the vertex shader outputs the vertex texture coordinates UV (passed "as-are"). These UV coordinates are available for each fragment, and they are computed by interpolating the values outputted by the vertex shader depending on the fragment position.

Once you have those coordinates, you only need two colors: the red and the yellow in your case (in *Bahbar* answer corresponds to *color0* and *color1* uniforms). Then, mix those colors depending on the UV coordinates of the specific fragment. (*)

(*) Here is the power of shaders: you can specify different interpolation methods by simply modifying the shader source. Linear, Bilinear or Spline interpolation are implemented by specifying additional uniforms to the fragment shader.

Good practice!

Comment: i've tried any amount of triangles, even the one you suggested "4 corners and 1 extra point in middle" but the results are always the same as using two triangles (except that the shape changes slightly, but it still shows "seams", and i still wont get it perfectly like i want). could you help making this with a shader, perhaps? i was thinking i could calculate the gradient myself, but the problem i have is: how to send the 4 corner color values for the fragment shader (and if this even is how i should do it?, so i need advices on that too...)

Comment: added the version example you suggested, it still doesnt work like it should, look at the image (or the link i left in case the image doesnt work)

Answer (score 0):

Do all of your vertices have the same depth (Z) value, and are all of your triangles completely on-screen? If so, then you should have no problem getting a "perfect" color gradient over a quad made from two triangles with glColor. If not, then it's possible that your OpenGL implementation treats colors poorly.

This leads me to suspect that you may have a very old or strange OpenGL implementation. I recommend that you tell us what platform you're using, and what version of OpenGL you have...?

Without any more information, I recommend you attempt writing a shader, and avoid telling OpenGL that you want a "color." If possible, tell it that you want a "texcoord" but treat it like a color anyway. This trick has worked in some cases where color accuracy is too low.

Comment: yes, it is 2d. yes they are completely on screen (why would this matter anyways? although, ive seen opengl rendering getting ugly with NO DRIVERS if triangles gets partially out of screen, but i do this for people with opengl drivers)

Comment: hmm, by treating texcoord as color, you mean i would use the numerical value of it to blend the colors by using the 4 corner colors? could you give some advice how should i do this? i have no idea, i only know how to get the texture color value, or the glColor value... but i dont know how to send 4 color values into fragment shader (nor i am sure is this the way it should be done).

Comment: i added example images of the problem now.

Comment: @Rookie: I don't see any images.  You don't have enough rep to add them directly to your question, so paste links and one of us can add the image.

Comment: argh, it shouldnt show it to me then if nobody else can see it... added a link now.