# OpenGL ES 2.0 Quad Gradient

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl, opengl-es

How can one draw a quad gradient with OpenGL ES 2.0?

Unfortunately OpenGL ES 2.0 does not support Quads natively. I'd love to attach a different color to each of the four quad-vertices so that OpenGL would draw a nice gradient between these four points/colors. (just like it does with 3 vertices and a triangle)

How can one get the exact same look with GL_TRIANGLES?

Comment: What you want seems to be _bilinear_ interpolation across the rectangle. Textures basically provide that functionality. However, you can't just assign your color values to each vertex as a vertex attribute. You need a way to get access to all 4 colors in the vertex shaders.

Comment: So you mean I could pass all 4 colors with each vertex? How would one calculate the result color in the vertex shader then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenGL: How to render perfect rectangular gradient?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359258/opengl-how-to-render-perfect-rectangular-gradient)

Comment: It's not a duplicate as I don't want to use a texture every time and it does not answer the question that I asked @derhass

Comment: If you want to interpolate between 4 values then they cannot be vertex attributes, because you can't have more than 3 of those at a time.  You either need to use a texture, or use a uniform value with the four colors and use texture coordinates to manually do the interpolation in the fragment shader.  Using a 2x2 texture basically gives you the same interpolation without a bunch of manual computation in the fragment shader and may be faster.  Regardless, you're facing the same problem as the other question, so yes, it's a duplicate.

Comment: But isn't it ineffective to make a new texture every time I need to render a different color? I actually don't even understand the answer in this other post as the example image can't be seen any longer. And they only seem to speak about two colors.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw a triangle strip with the same vertices as a quad, you should get the same output visually as you would have with the quad.

The only trick is that you need to reorder your vertices.  Consider this shape...

```
UL---UR
|     |
|     |
|     |
LL---LR
```

Perhaps you've ordered your vertices `LL, LR, UR, UL`.  This produces a counter-clockwise winding of the face producing the whole of the shape.  However, it won't work for a triangle strip, because strips require that the last two vertices of the previous triangle make up one of the edges of the next triangle.  That means that the second and third vertices here need to be a diagonal, but instead here they are an edge (`LR, UR` is the right edge of the quad).

If you reorder your vertices like this `LR, UR, LL, UL` then you get the following result when treated as a triangle strip..

```
UL---UR
|    /|
|  /  |
|/    |
LL---LR
```

OpenGL will then interpret this as two triangles with the vertices `LR, UR, LL` and `LL, UR, UL`.

A given quad *strip* can similarly be converted into a triangle strip by reordering the vertices.

Comment: So you say, if I use a Triangle Strip with 4 different colors there won't be a hard edge when going from UL to LR? Will it seamlessly blend the colors between UL and LR?

Comment: I see what you mean now, sorry I misunderstood your question.  However, there's still an easy solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359258/opengl-how-to-render-perfect-rectangular-gradient

Answer (score 0):

Jherico's answer addresses the "make a quad from triangles" part, and derhass' comment hints at a solution to the gradient interpolation part. Bringing them together...

Send your quad as a tristrip (that's better than triangles — you don't need to specify vertices twice, and it costs time to send your VBO to the GPU). Add texture coordinates to each vertex:

```
UL: (0.0, 1.0)
UR: (1.0, 1.0)
LL: (0.0, 0.0)
LR: (1.0, 0,0)
```

Then, in your fragment shader, instead of using the texture coordinates (the vertex attribute passed thru the vertex shader as a varying) to lookup in a texture, set your output color based on the texcoord:

```
varying vec2 texcoord;

main() {
    // simple black-white vertical gradient
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texcoord.y);
}
```

Comment: Now this sounds promising, thank you! Just one question left: How do I interpolate between four colors then? Would I pass all four colors to the fragment shader and interpolate between them based on the texCoord? Or is it somehow possible to directly calculate this in the vertex shader and hand it to the fragment shader as a varying?

Comment: And another one: Would this still work drawing distorted rectangles? E.g. when having two of the vertices overlap and the quad forming a triangle (the gradient should look like a slice from an angular gradient then).